# I need SQL query that calculates specific delta metric

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help to write a SQL query as I don't have enough knowledge.

Let say I have this table

```
Time |Item| TOTAL
-----------------
000  |   1|   111
-----------------
000  |   2|   113
-----------------
001  |   1|   113
-----------------
001  |   2|   143
-----------------
002  |   1|   173
-----------------
002  |   2|   183
```

I need an SQL which based on the time will calculate the delta between the `Total` of the  `Item` of that time and the previous.

```
Time |Item| TOTAL
-----------------
000  |   1|     0
-----------------
000  |   2|     0
-----------------
001  |   1|     2
-----------------
001  |   2|    30
-----------------
002  |   1|    60
-----------------
002  |   2|    40
```

So for Time=0, Item=1 the total will be 0 as we don't have previous time.
For Time=1, Item=1 the total will be 2 (113 (Item=1, Time=1)-111(Item=1, Time=0))
For Time=1, Item=2 the total will be 30 (143 (Item=2, Time=1)-113(Item=2, Time=0))
and so on.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If MySQL 8.0, then you could use the [LAG() window function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/).

```
create table table1 (
  read_time integer, 
  item integer, 
  total integer
  );
  
insert into table1 values 
(0, 1, 111), 
(0, 2, 113), 
(1, 1, 113), 
(1, 2, 143), 
(2, 1, 173), 
(2, 2, 183);
```

---

```
select read_time, 
 item, 
 coalesce(total - prior_total, 0) as my_total
from (
  select read_time, 
   item, 
   total, 
   lag(total, 1) over (partition by item order by read_time) as prior_total
   from table1
  )z
order by 1,2;
```

| read_time | item | my_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 30 |
| 2 | 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 2 | 40 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bfgofoMWKFznneEDQvdzNt/0)